# Using a darcs-like workflow with Git

Tags: git

I spent quite a bit of time using Darcs, but now I'm using a tool that foisted git upon me.  I'd like to figure out how to use my old workflow with git.  It seems like it ought to translate to git, but I get a strange error when I try it.

So suppose I have a "projects" directory which contains project-repo.  And suppose I have to add feature 'foo' to the project.  So I might do:

```
darcs clone project-repo project.foo
cd project.foo
```

and then make my changes and "commit" to the history:

```
darcs record
```

and finally merge the history into the main repo:

```
darcs push
```

Now I can trash project.foo, or keep it, if it seems sensible.

Okay, so I gave this a go, in a project using chef:

```
git clone chef chef.foo
<make changes>
git commit -m "changes message"
git push
```

But I'm getting an error.

```
Counting objects: 23, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (16/16), done.
Writing objects: 100% (17/17), 2.29 KiB, done.
Total 17 (delta 9), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (17/17), done.
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: error: 
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: error: other way.
remote: error: 
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
To /home/foo/dev/chef
! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
```

Okay, I guess the error isn't particularly strange, but why doesn't it "just work"?  What can I do to, you know, use it as a distributed vcs?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I just tried this:

```
cd ..
cd project-repo
git pull ../project.foo
```

and it successfully pulled the patches.  It should would be nice if I could push things into the repo, though...

Comment: You *can*, but it's not recommended, because it could end up with the remote repository having a working directory that doesn't reflect its repository state. If you're sure you want to go ahead, you just need to follow the instructions in the error message: `You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some other way.`